# ios 10 - UITabBarController UITabBarItem - items slow to render

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, ios10, uitabbaritem

Upon login the initial display of my UI worked fine in iOS 9 with the UITabBarController showing all icons appropriately but in iOS 10 there is a noticeable delay of up to 5 - 10 seconds without any error in the log.

I've posted a bug to Apple ID- 29127274

The fix is below...

-J

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that cause the problem:

```
@implementation MyTabBarController
```

//...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //the code below was causing the delay ... this worked find in iOS9

    //tried legacy #define style
    //[self setSelectedIndex:int(SelectedLandingToTab)]; 

    //tried extern style .... both fail
    //[self setSelectedIndex:SELECTEDLANDINGTAB];
}

//...
@end
```

If you comment out the setSelectedIndex then the UITabBar shows properly without delay.

-J